# Is there a way to process the linux source tree using the config file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, device-tree

I am wondering if there is a way to use my `.config` file for building the Linux kernel and create another source tree with only the code which will actually be used in the build. For instance, if I choose not to include a certain driver, the code for that driver will be left out and all `#ifdef CONFIG_<driver>` sections will be removed from the resulting code.

I would like to be able to run the C preprocessor on the entire source tree for the kernel without running any of the actual compilation steps so that I can examine the full codebase of the kernel running on my system without any of the extra code included in the Linux project which will be unused when I compile my kernel.

I was wondering if there was any specific tool or step of `make` commands that would allow me to run a program like `unifdef` on the entire source tree using what is in my `.config` file.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What you want to do is technically possible with a bunch of scripts / make commands, but I don't know if there readily exists any tool/build option to do it easily.

Comment: The generic tool for that is [unifdef](http://dotat.at/prog/unifdef/), but of course you'll need to invoke it properly so that it handles your `.config` file and produces another tree. Also take a look at the [unifdef.c file in the Linux Kernel tree](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/unifdef.c).

Comment: Not really - but you can parse the build log and find all files actually compiled. (Or, hook the compiler command and log the input files). Then remove all the rest from the code base... Unifdef only removes parts of files based on its' knowledge of defined macros, it is probably not what you want.